# Create Cloudwatch event rule which will trigger AWS MQ Python Lambda Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-mq

I need to create a Cloudwatch event which will trigger automatically my Python AWS Lambda function.

I followed below link but was unsuccessful.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html

Please suggest.

[Cloudwatch event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAUu9.png)

[Lambda function mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZj1h.png)

Comment: What error are you getting? What have you done so far?

Comment: @ShivRajawat I have created cloudwatch event rule and mapped to Lambda function. When I send messages to AWS-MQ, Lambda function is not triggering automatically.
I need to achieve below scenario-
https://github.com/aws-samples/amazonmq-invoke-aws-lambda